# How to get only 1 role from user

Tags: users, user-roles

I have this code that will display all the roles for that particular user, but I only need to display 1 role from the user. I have installed bbpress so the code below will display out 2 roles.

```
$user = new WP_User( 1 );

if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
echo $role;                 
}
```

Result: Administrator Participant

How to display only the first role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    $first_role = array_shift($user->roles);
    echo $first_role;   
}
```

Function `array_shift` obtains the first element of the `$user->roles` array.